# WebServices - How can i catch ConnectException?

Tags: java, web-services, exception

I have two servers (primary and a secondary) and the corresponding clients. Both are using the **same WSDL contract** (so I can't change the operations) because I want this server to be **fault tolerant**. Basically what I am doing to verify the primary server is up and running is pinging with the secondary. When the primary server doesn't answer I know this server is down. My main problem is when I try to ping a disconnected server it sends:

`javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

How can I catch this exception if it is never thrown in the body of the function? Or is there another way to verify if a server is up?

Here is the code:

**Secondary server**

```
private void isAlive(){
        String alive = null;
        try {
            Client client = new Client(uddiURL, wsName);
            while(true){                
                try {
                    alive = client.ping("alive");
                } catch (ConnectException e1) {
                    System.out.println("Primary server is down");
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(alive.equals("alive")){
                    System.out.println("Still up");
                }
            }
        } catch (BrokerClientException e) {
            System.err.print("Failed to create BrokerClient");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ;
        }
    }
```

**Primary Server**

```
public String ping(String message){
        return message;
}
```

Comment: More to the point, why are you pinging? I'm against this. HTTP and TCP are the most widely used protocols on the planet, and neither needs it. Why do you think you do?

Comment: @EJP I need to ping because the secondary server needs to know when the primary is down to register in the UDDI. The main purpose to this "pinging" is for the client doesn't notice that the server where changed

Comment: You could catch "javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException" and search for the text "Connection refused". However, connection refused can be anything, not just the server down. Agree with EJP, there is a better way to monitor a heart-beat.

Comment: @Minh Kieu In my scenario the only fault that will exist is if someone SIGKILL the process. My problem is that how can I catch that exception if ping never throws it?

Comment: What sending the ping message and primary server is down. What error do you see? Also, another suggestion is to turn it on it head. Get the primary server to send the message to the standby server(s). If within the timeout period and no message is received then you can assume the primary server is not active?

Comment: @MinhKieu Thanks for the suggestion I'll try that. I think that'll solve my problems.